# Change default workspace in Octave

Tags: octave

I freshly installed Octave on my Computer and was wondering if I could switch the default workspace from `/home/user` to, let's say,`/home/user/Octave` but could not find any advice online... I am using Ubuntu 14.04 if that's of any importance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change default Octave environment by creating .octaverc file in your home directory and putting your commands there.

1. create a .octaverc file in your home directory

   `$ touch ~/.octaverc`
2. put your desired command in that file.

   `cd ("~/Octave")`

or, you can use this one-line command to do the same as above.

```
$ echo "cd (\"~/Octave\")" > ~/.octaverc
```